# Adjust your boxes based on windows size in c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have been working on a project in c# and I have the starting box size pretty small around, 700px by 450px.

Everything looks great on that size but when I maximize it, all the forms and etc stay the same size and just stick to the corner of the window.

I am curious if there is a way to get the boxes to adjust accordingly to the size of the actual windows form so if they click on the maximize button it doesn't look weird.

I have looked quite a bit online and everything I have tried doesn't seem to work. Also I am using visual studio 2013.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't suppose you can switch to WPF? It is much easier to accomplish this in that technology.

Comment: In the properties of objects in a form you can set the edges of an item to be "Anchor" -- set all 4 sides as Anchor not just two.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand what's going on, and please excuse me if I'm just saying things you already know, but controls inside of forms can be anchored. This helps because--for instance-- if a control is anchored on all sides then no matter how the form they reside in is resized they will grow with it.
The anchor property is in the property window.
As far as forms inside of forms that you would just have to grab the size property of the mdi window and grow the child forms based on this.
You could use the resize event in mdi form to fire off an interface method that all of your child forms implement maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use the `Anchor` or `Dock` properties to position and size controls relative to their container in `WinForms`